# Was Steve Martin and Robin William's stage performance of Waiting for Godot ever released on film?

Tags: waiting-for-godot, robin-williams, come-inside-my-mind

After watching the HBO bio-documentary on Robin Williams titled ["Come Inside My Mind"](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt7689966), one of the things I was very interested in was that Steven Martin and Robin Williams acted together in Samuel Beckett's classic play "Waiting for Godot". There is some footage of this play shown in the documentary and I found a [listing for a DVD in the New York Public Library System](http://catalog.nypl.org/search/o176090386). But is this the only copy available?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, this was never released on film.  The The New York Public Library's Theatre on Film and Tape Archive records most theater productions for archival purposes, but only makes them available to qualified researchers.  Typically, if you are deemed qualified you will receive a copy of the production with a very large watermark running across the video.  You would then submit the timestamps of the sections you wish to use, restricted to some varying short amount of time, and then you would be provided with only those segments on a disc without the watermark.  Many major filmhouses do this as well.

There's a very famous one whose name escapes me at the moment which deals with live concert footage, they were the first ones known to have the Rush show from Capital Theater in 1976 (which has since been officially released by Rush) as well as a Boston concert from 1979, among a large selection of others.

Comment: That's interesting. Why wouldn't they make that stuff more available? Strange.

Comment: Simply put; money.  They pay for the rights to be the sole suppliers, and then charge people to use the clips.  But in a perfect world, they really should make them available for free.